# Prove the solution of the differential equation C(y)=0 has a given form

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two constant-coefficient operators whose characteristic polynomials have no roots in common. Then let $C=AB$. Prove that every solution of the differential equation $C(y) = 0$ has the form $y=y_1+y_2$, where $A(y_1)=0$ and $B(y_2)=0$.

Was thinking a proof by saying the solutions of $C$ come from a linear combination of the solutions of $A$ and $B$, but not sure if that's valid.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to MSE. What have you tried?, what are your thoughts on this?,where have you stuck.Sharing your work would help the users to understand what you are asking and where you need help. HAPPY MATH SOLVING.

Comment: Made an edit to the post.